# to_avro function for schema registry not found in spark-avro

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I'm trying to write to a kafka sink using this documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html#example-with-schema-registry

However, I can't find to_avro function with more than one parameter in spark-avro(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.11). Does anybody know if it has been moved/renamed or I should use another library? Thank you!

Comment: can you specify the spark version ?

Comment: Hi. I'm using spark 2.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `spark 3.0`, these functions has been moved to `org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions.scala` object

check this - [spark-repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/avro/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/avro/functions.scala#L89)
jira- [SPARK-26870](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26870)

Also the databricks doc you are referring is based on `spark 3`